# What is the order of using blocks in Ruby

Tags: ruby, block

I am creating a gem to support some Mailing from the command line. I use some Gem.
I am using the [Mail Gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail). As you can see in the description of `mail gem` is something like this.

```rb
mail = Mail.new do
  from    'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
  to      'you@test.lindsaar.net'
  subject 'This is a test email'
  body    File.read('body.txt')
end
```

In the block I call the methods from the `Mail` class (from, to, subject, body). This makes sense so I build it in my own mailer class

```rb
def initialize(mail_settings, working_hours)
  @mail_settings = mail_settings
  @working_hours = working_hours
  @mailer = Mail.new do
    to mail_settings[:to]
    from mail_settings[:from]
    subject mail_settings[:subject]
    body "Start #{working_hours[:start]} \n\
          Ende #{working_hours[:end]}\n\
          Pause #{working_hours[:pause]}"
  end
end
```

This looks straight forward. Just call the block und fill in my values I get through the constructor. **Now** comes my question.

I tried to put out the body construction for the mail into a separated method. But I cannot use it in the `Mail` constructor of the gem.

```rb
module BossMailer
  class Mailer
  def initialize(mail_settings, working_hours)
    @mail_settings = mail_settings
    @working_hours = working_hours
    @mailer = Mail.new do
      to mail_settings[:to]
      from mail_settings[:from]
      subject mail_settings[:subject]
      body mail_body
    end
  end

  def mail
    @mailer.delivery_method :smtp, address: "localhost", port: 1025
    @mailer.deliver
  end

  def mail_body
    "Start #{working_hours[:start]} \n\
    Ende #{working_hours[:end]}\n\
    Pause #{working_hours[:pause]}"
  end
end
```

end

This error came out this code.
[image]

That means I cannot use my class method or class variable (beginning with `@a`) in this block.

**Questions**

What is the order of the execution in a Block? If I set my variable `@mail_settings`, I can't use it in the block. Is Ruby searching for `@mail_settings` in `Mail` class where I give the block to? Why can I use the given parameter from the `BossMailer::Mailer` constructor through the block and no error appears?

And why does this works if I am using and variable to parse the content into the block? (`body_content = mail_body`) works!

```rb
def initialize(mail_settings, working_hours)
  @mail_settings = mail_settings
  @working_hours = working_hours
  body_content = mail_body
  @mailer = Mail.new do
    to mail_settings[:to]
    from mail_settings[:from]
    subject mail_settings[:subject]
    body body_content
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about the context.

```
mail = Mail.new do
  from    'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
  to      'you@test.lindsaar.net'
  subject 'This is a test email'
  body    File.read('body.txt')
end
```

`from`, `to` methods (and the rest) are methods on [`Mail::Message`](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/0f9393bb3ef1344aa76d6dac28db3a4934c65087/lib/mail/message.rb) instance. For you to be able to call them in this nice DSL-manner, the block you pass to constructor is [instance_eval'ed](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/0f9393bb3ef1344aa76d6dac28db3a4934c65087/lib/mail/message.rb#L131-L133).

What this means is that inside of this block, `self` is no longer your mailer, but a mail message instead. As a result, your mailer method is not accessible.

Instead of `instance_eval`, they could have just `yield` or `block.call`, but this wouldn't make the DSL possible.

As to why the local variable works: it's because ruby blocks are lexically-scoped *closures* (meaning, they retain local context of their declaration. If there was a local variable visible from where the block is defined, it'll remember the variable and its value when the block is called)

#### Alternative approach

Don't use the block form. Use this: https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/0f9393bb3ef1344aa76d6dac28db3a4934c65087/lib/mail/message.rb#L92-L96

```
mail = Mail.new
mail['from'] = 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
mail[:to]    = 'you@test.lindsaar.net'
mail.subject 'This is a test email'
mail.body    = 'This is a body'
```

#### Code

Try commenting/uncommenting some lines.

```
class Mail
  def initialize(&block)
    # block.call(self) # breaks DSL
    instance_eval(&block) # disconnects methods of mailer
  end

  def to(email)
    puts "sending to #{email}"
  end

end

class Mailer
  def admin_mail
    # get_recipient = 'vasya@example.com'
    Mail.new do
      to get_recipient
    end
  end

  def get_recipient
    'sergio@example.com'
  end
end


Mailer.new.admin_mail
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `mail_body` is evaluated in the context of `Mail::Message` and not in the context of your `BossMailer::Mailer` class. Consider the following examples:

```
class A
  def initialize
    yield
  end
end

class B
  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval { block.call }
  end
end

class C
  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

class Caller
  def test
    A.new { hi 'a' }
    B.new { hi 'b' }
    C.new { hi 'c' }
  end

  def hi(x)
    puts "hi there, #{x}"
  end
end

Caller.new.test
```

This will get you

```
hi there, a
hi there, b
`block in test': undefined method `hi' for #<C:0x286e1c8> (NoMethodError)
```

Looking at the gem's code, this is exactly what happens:

[`Mail.new` just passes the block given to `Mail::Message`'s constructor](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/mail.rb#L50).

[The said constructor works exactly as the `C` case above](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/message.rb#L132).

---

`instance_eval` basically changes what `self` is in the current context.

About why `B` and `C` cases work differently - you can think that `&` will 'change' the `block` object from proc to block (yes, my choice of variable name wasn't great there). More on the difference [here](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/).

Comment: Your case `B` is irrelevant here, as it is effectively exactly like case `A` (no mail message methods are available)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, it is not what happens, but it is relevant to the explanation. It was intended to show how block's context is determined in ruby in general.

Comment: what do you mean, it is not what happens? The block does not attempt to use any methods from `B`. If it did, you'd see it fail.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, exactly, it doesn't. Most people would intuitively think that case `B` and `C` should be equivalent, because they expect both to be evaluated in the context of the new class constructor since they both use `instance_eval`. I wanted to show that this is not the case.

Comment: In this case, you should add more explanation of this point. As it is now, it's just confusing.

Comment: Not sure what is confusing about it. The OP expected to be in the `A` case, I said he is in the `C` case and just added `B` as a remark of a common gotcha.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing. You just added a piece of code, without any comments. It just sits there, hoping to be obvious, but it's not.

Comment: As of right now, I think this achieves a perfect balance between explanatory power and conciseness. To use more words would be to make assumptions about OP's Ruby knowledge. In case he asks further questions, I will clarify.

Comment: Sure, I'm just sharing my opinion :)

Comment: What about future readers though, with varying levels of proficiency in ruby? This answer is meant to be useful to them too. A bit more explanation can't hurt.

Comment: What about future readers that know what `instance_eval` does, but the answer just didn't occur to them? If they don't, there would be much more value for them to go and read about it instead of me explaining it in a very narrow context. This isn't the 'give me quick copy-paste solution' kind of question.

Comment: I get the point here. Maybe some explanation or links to `instance_eval` and the different on passing `&block` or calling it, would make it in some point easier to follow, but I get some good points. Thank you

Comment: Added a clarification and a link.